# Zip utilities and HD lifespan

Tags: external-hard-drive, zip, 7-zip, lifespan

I have a portable HD that I do my backups on. Is there any indication that using zip utilities such as 7-zip and PeaZip (I use this one) have an effect on a drives lifespan when being used on them. For example, if I zip a directory on my portable hard drive using Peazip, can they make a portable HD life shorter?

Answer (score 0):

Zip utilities will not wear out your drives faster than any other program. It's just regular usage.

Hard drives do not "care" about what type of file you are writing to them.